# Windows Boot Manager works very slow

Tags: windows-8, boot, performance

I want to reboot from Windows 10 into Linux from USB. I am doing it by restart with pressed shift key. But it is very slow. After press restart and shift together I wait more than 1 minute on black screen. No cursor, no disk activity, nothing only waiting. After more than minute I will se standart Windows Boot Manager light blue screen with options to repair, restore and other boot options. Exactly how i expect it.

Boot into normal mode its OK.

When I had Windows 8 it worked fast (under 10 sec), after update to 8.1 it was slower (under 20 sec) but it was acceptable and now when I had cleanly reinstalled to Windows 10 its very slow (more than minute, last attempt take more than 2 minutes).

I suppose that it is caused by NVRAM where are saved informations that Windows Boot Manager uses to advanced boot and there are some useless things that was saved by many Windows installations which i have done. I assume so because computer in black screen time don't use disk and problem was not resolved after clean disk installation (before installing Windows 10 I removed all partitions).

How to make it fast as it was in Windows 8 era? Do you think that my assumption is right?

Comment: You know you can also bring up the device selection prompt directly from the POST screen, right? You may have to turn of Fast Boot (in your BIOS). No need to use the Advanced Reboot menu.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [15 Windows 10 problems - and how to fix them](http://www.itpro.co.uk/operating-systems/25802/15-windows-10-problems-and-how-to-fix-them-4) :

> Like Windows 8 before it, Windows 10 uses a hybrid boot to enable fast
>   boot times. When you shut the system down, apps and app processes are
>   terminated, but the Windows kernel itself is hibernated to allow for a
>   faster restart. In theory, it's great, but it seems to still be very
>   slow for some Windows 10 users.

Disable it by :

1. Go to **Control Panel** / **Power Options**
2. In the left-hand pane click **Choose what the power buttons do**.
3. Click **Change settings that are currently unavailable**
4. Scroll down and un-tick **Turn on fast start-up**
5. Click **Save changes**.

This should prevent very slow starts on affected PCs. Some users report that if they subsequently reboot, re-trace their steps and re-enable fast start-up, the problem remains cured.

Answer (score 0):

I avoid using the Windows boot manager by having a dual boot installation with Lubuntu. It goes as fast as it takes Windows to shut down. I got there following the steps from help.ubuntu.com to install from an UEFI-only disk, after buying the computer with Windows pre-installed.

It will only help if you want a permanent installation on hard drive, though; i.e. not helping to boot from USB or optical drive.